# How to deal with "OverflowError: size does not fit in an int" error?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am running a Spark job wherein everything works if I perform my calculations on the sample data (think of ~1000 rows). But when I try to perform the same calculations on a larger dataset, I get

```
19/07/20 14:21:53 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 198.0 in stage 150.0 (TID 21928, 10.46.225.176, executor 17): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 403, in main
    process()
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 398, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2516, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2516, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 352, in func
    return f(iterator)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1886, in _mergeCombiners
    merger.mergeCombiners(iterator)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 289, in mergeCombiners
    self._spill()
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 317, in _spill
    self.serializer.dump_stream([(k, v)], streams[h])
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 417, in dump_stream
    bytes = self.serializer.dumps(vs)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 679, in dumps
    return zlib.compress(self.serializer.dumps(obj), 1)
OverflowError: size does not fit in an int

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:490)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:626)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:609)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:444)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIterator(MemoryStore.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsBytes(MemoryStore.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1187)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1161)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1096)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1161)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:883)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:302)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1481)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:503)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What triggers it? I think something during the final stages of collect operation

`rdd.take(500)`

So far, I have tried:

1. Repartitioning to 4000 partitions. Did not help/there is no way of me to understand if it did.
2. Use a large cluster - m5.xlarge + r4.4xlarge (16 workers). Would using a smaller cluster help with this. Is it possible that a large cluster might be causing some serialization issues?
3. Using Python 2.7 since the libraries I am working with are written in 2.7. I saw a post stating that there might be an issue with zlib, but I am not sure how to fix it or workaround it.

I feel like I have exhausted all of my limited understanding with this problem. Would really appreciate any guidance or things that might be helpful. Please don't mark it is a duplicate since I have checked the couple of posts around it and found nothing useful out of it.

Comment: support to python2 for spark is coming to end. [link](https://spark.apache.org/news/plan-for-dropping-python-2-support.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you are hitting the 2G limit of zlib for single buffer. If possible, update your python version.

Try the following to see if that's the case for you. The second line should fail.

```
> python2 -c "import zlib; zlib.compress(b'a' * (2**31 - 1))"
> python2 -c "import zlib; zlib.compress(b'a' * (2**31))"
```

More on this: https://bugs.python.org/issue27130

Comment: So it might sound weird, but when I doubled the size of the cluster, I no longer have the problem. Might you know what might be causing it?

Comment: Well doubling the size of the cluster is basically reducing the size of the partitions per node so i'd bet it'd work. Try the opposite to see if the size of the dataset that exceeds 2g limit is causing the problem. In any case, try to come up with a smaller yet optimal sized partitions per node.